# golang. Правильное подключение к бд

Tags: mysql, golang

как правильно подключатся к бд?

```
var (db *sql.DB)
        
func dbConnect {
        
  database, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@/productdb")  
  db = database;
}

func GetDB() *sql.DB {
  return db;
}

func CloseDB() error {
  return db.Close();
}
```

Как лучше всего подключатся к бд. И стоит ли закрывать соединение после каждой обработки запроса. То есть, я открываю бд, я добавлю значение в бд, после запроса я закрываю её. - хорошо ли это? Или стоит открыть один раз бд и просто обрабатывать запрос, и так каждый раз. Простите за такой вопрос, но я немного не понимаю как правильно реализовать подключение.

Comment: Ваш вопрос не зависит от языка программирования. Если погуглить, то можно найти как соображения за то, чтобы держать соединения, так и  за то, чтобы закрывать сразу. Например, можете посмотреть дискуссию здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312702/is-it-safe-to-keep-database-connections-open-for-long-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря как ты хочешь/задумал.
Открывать каждый раз заново соединение - плохая практика.

Единственное что нужно не забыть сделать - закрыть соединение когда ты закончишь работу с соединением

```
// Подключаешься к БД в функции main
dbConnect()
defer db.Close()
// Продолжение программы...
```